# Access origin to restrict sites, but allow everything when connected to a specific site

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

I am using Intel XDK, but I think that it is a more general question that would apply to Cordova and CORS.

I want to restrict my application to my domain:

`<access origin="https://www.example.com"/>`

However, my application uses Google+ sign-in. So, I also need:

`<access origin="https://accounts.google.com"/>`

But, Google also loads a couple of other sites which means that I also need to include a bunch of other sites, such as:

```
<access origin="https://accounts.youtube.com"/>
<access origin="https://ssl.gstatic.com"/>
<access origin="https://fonts.gstatic.com"/>
```

**The problem** is that Google sign-in may at any point change to include other sites, which would cause my app to break. Now, I imagine that Google sign-in has its own CORS protections, so I should be OK to allow anything loaded by it.

Is there a way to say something like 'Only allow my domain and this other domain, but allow everything that is loaded when connected to the other domain (accounts.google.com in this case)'? Or possibly: 'Only allow my domain and this other domain, but for the other domain rely on the CORS control enforced by the other domain'?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a Cordova configuration you need to do. Within the XDK it is done by going to the *Build Settings* section of the *Projects* tab. You'll see a field called *Domain List* where you can enter the list of domains to which you want to restrict your app's access. It is probably set to '*' -- which means "the entire world." If you hover over the (i) icon, to the right, it will provide you with a link to the Cordova docs that describe how to specify a white list of domains.

Note that in Cordova CLI 5 (which the XDK does not yet support), this changes (again) to a slightly different system. When the XDK does support that version of the Cordova system, the settings dialog will probably change, but the basic idea will still remain, a list of white-listed domains.

Comment: Yes, but how do I allow everything that Google loads (e.g. ssl.gstatic.com) without stating it explicitly. Otherwise if Google changes, my site breaks. As per the question in the last paragraph.

Comment: If you know in advance that everything loaded by Google will be *.google.com, you can use that notation. However, if you have no idea what the Google site will be loading your only option is to use a single * record in the domains list. Please see the Cordova docs for more details: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html